# How do I insert MapsActivity into a Fragment Container?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this code on the default MapsActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

And this on the Navigation Drawer MainActivity

```
MapsActivity fragment = new MapsActivity();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The second code I can manage to make it work with other fragments except the one with Maps.
What could be wrong?

Comment: You can't use FragmentTransaction to show an Activity... A FragmentActivity is not a Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the SupportMapFragment from the Activity, [the answer from cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580473/4409409) will work fine.

If you want custom functionality, and you want to keep it in the Fragment, you can create a Fragment that extends SupportMapFragment, for example:

```
public class MyCustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment 
                          implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public MyCustomMapFragment () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

Then you can use a FragmentTransaction to replace the container with your custom SupportMapFragment:

```
MyCustomMapFragment fragment = new MyCustomMapFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do so since the documentation says only using the `<fragment>` tag in the layout, but you could try this.

```
SupportMapFragment fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

There is also a [`newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#public-methods) method you can use to give options to the map, if you wish.